# If g and h are of same order in a finite group G, then there exists a group H, an extension of G such that g and h are conjugates in H .

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Actually, we have seen restriction of every structural space .
And, there are extensions also, like extension of a metric space into another .

I thought about extending a group, but I can't figure out how to implement closure operations and inverses .

And the question : Is the above statement true ???
If true, then how to relate the finiteness of G with it ???

[Consequences of Britton's Lemma
Edit
Most basic properties of HNN-extensions follow from Britton's Lemma. These consequences include the following facts:

The natural homomorphism from G to {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} is injective, so that we can think of {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} as containing G as a subgroup.
Every element of finite order in {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} is conjugate to an element of G.
Every finite subgroup of {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} is conjugate to a finite subgroup of G.
If {\displaystyle H\neq G} {\displaystyle H\neq G} and {\displaystyle K\neq G} {\displaystyle K\neq G} then {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} {\displaystyle G*_{\alpha }} contains a subgroup isomorphic to a free group of rank two.]- source  HNN extension - Wikipedia

But, the proof of Britton's lemma is not provided, then how to approach ???

Answer (score 1):

There's the [HNN extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension). Let $a$ and $b$ be the elements in question
and let $H$ be given by the the following presentation. Define $G$ by generators
and relations, add a new generator $t$ and a new relation $at=tb$. One problem
is that the HNN extension in general has infinite index, so if $G$ is finite
then in general $H$ won't be.

Comment: To Lord Shark the Unknown, Sir, the above statement was written in a question paper and the question was  to prove or disprove the statement , so are you hinting towards any counter-example ???

Comment: No, he says that it is always possible using representation theory, just that $H$ will, in general, not be finite.

Comment: To Dirk, so Sir , can you sketch up the proof for me ???