# If two elements have the same order then they belong to the same conjugacy class

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have this question to prove:

> Prove that if two elements are conjugated then they have the same order. is it true vice versa?

I solved the first part like they solved in this question [If two elements belong to the same conjugacy class then they have the same order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121347/if-two-elements-belong-to-the-same-conjugacy-class-then-they-have-the-same-order), but how can i solve the vice versa?

Comment: It is not true in general that if two elements have the same order then they are conjugates. A simple example could be in $S_4$ where the permutations $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$ both have order $2$, but are not conjugates of each other. Edit: Oh yeah, finite abelian groups are better examples :) .

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse proposition is in general not true.
For example, in a finite abelian group, there are many elements of the same order, while each conjugacy class consists of a single element.

Comment: So, if i want to demonstrate that, i could take a finite abelian group and say that 2 elements a,b have the same order but a is conjugated only with itself and the same for b?

Comment: @BigMautone sounds good to me.

Comment: If this is an assignment, make sure that you choose the finite abelian to have order greater than two, and if it happens to be cyclic of order a power of two, make sure not to choose the identity or the unique element of order two.

Answer (score 1):

The converse doesn't hold in general, but another version is true:

**Theorem:** If $h,g$ are two elements of a finite group $G$ with ${\rm ord}(g)={\rm ord}(h)$, then there exists a group $H\supseteq G$ such that $g$ and $h$ are conjugate in $H$.

Reference: [This MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273215/given-two-elements-g-h-in-a-finite-group-g-of-the-same-order-does-there-exi), and

[If g and h are of same order in a finite group G, then there exists a group H, an extension of G such that g and h are conjugates in H .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273469/if-g-and-h-are-of-same-order-in-a-finite-group-g-then-there-exists-a-group-h-a)

Comment: I find it funny that the proof of that statement uses the symmetric group, which is the example I had originally come up with somehow. The proof is just to let the larger group be the symmetric group on $G$. You can then identify the elements of $G$ with the permutations they induce on $G$ by left action, and elements of the same order induce permutations with the same cycle type, and are thus conjugate in this group.

Comment: @Asinomás Yes, indeed. This proof is written [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Isomorphic_iff_potentially_conjugate_in_finite), in case someone wants to have a reference.